# How do this site filters out answers from scholar vs non scholar?

Tags: discussion, moderation, quality-control, scholars

Islam to Muslims is an essential part of their life. It is not an academic or technical thing to play around, so I was wondering how does this site filter out answers from scholars vs non scholars?

Secondly, is there any bias from the moderators in choosing or deleting the posts and/or answers.

Answer (score 2):

The site doesn't filter anything.  [We do not check credentials at the door](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/452/22).

The responsibility of ensuring answer quality lies entirely on the voting community; good answers get upvoted, bad answers get downvoted and possibly deleted.  [The Stack Exchange model](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) is built around the idea that *experts* know what is or is not a good answer, so attracting experts who can properly vote on those answers is *incumbent* to making the site succeed.

Moderators are users like any other.  If they choose to delete a post, it's because they feel that the post needs to be deleted (and they will often leave a comment explaining *why* they made that decision), but deletion is an ability that any user with sufficient reputation can wield and like any other vote is prone to the subjective whims of the voter.  Sure people can make mistakes, but if you [assume good faith](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1155/22) instead of accusing others of bias just because you disagree, the problem can usually be resolved peaceably on meta.

Comment: This question was not meant for meta, it was meant for Muslims who posts answers to important religious issues...which builds a Muslims life and world view...This question should not be moved here..btw My answers were deleted that is why I talk of bias of those moderators allegedly Muslims and Islamic

Comment: btw correct knowledge is not voted to correctness

Comment: @LogicianUnix Questions regarding the site itself are *exactly* what meta is for.  If you're finding your posts getting deleted, I would strongly suggest you take the time to check out our [tour] page and peruse our [help] section: The Stack Exchange model is very different from a typical Internet forum, as are the sorts of questions/answers/behaviour we expect here.

Answer (score 1):

If this site only accepted answers from scholars it would be (as we say in Arabic) "like the palm of your hand" - that is: empty.

Comment: @ aasheq, you gave an interesting exmaple (expression) !

Answer (score 1):

Every stack exchange site has the same basic principal, "cite when you write".

Backup your scholarly claim which you are making.

Here

- one line answers
- answers with totally new 'unheard' claims **without support**
- answers from other schools of thought not asked for in the question

Are even may not be wrong but will come down eventually, if the community understands and adheres by their role and rules of **voting**.

So, for an explorer, what remains is the trust the whole community together provides that some answer which is on top is *correct* and relevant.

There are not many scholars out here who can freshly answer your question. But **experts** of this site can come closer to being one with the support of the rest of the community, when the answerer can stay assured that he will be corrected by the rest of the community either by down voting, or informing what's wrong in the comments (in case if he is trying to act smart).

Comment: So cite when you write makes something acceptable in Islam? What if the citation is from Shia books? What if the citation is disagreed upon by jurists, or the citation subject matter is disregarded or abrogated? Now scholarly claim, back up requires you to either be a scholar or learnt from a scholar...the rest of the points are just plain whims

Comment: Vote.............that is the key for everything......most citations r directly from quran or hadiths which the questioner is interested in... and then depends on voting..... plz refer to the link in mr gold's answer for further info...

Comment: U can read more from here http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/quality-of-references-while-answering @LogicianUnix

Comment: Here http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: I thought Islam was renowned to conclude its problems through reason, and not a social site of voters..anyway good luck with ur democracy in Islamic theology and Islamic law....

Comment: Why r u missing the point, that people will vote only if they most of the time from raw Hadith and Qur'an uncooked. People are not fools to fall for stupid reasoning written without enough references (most of the time raw from Qur'an and Hadith). Personally, I'll tell you from my point, I barely refer Hadith to answer and almost never ever from articles written from other scholars cuz I donno any. @LogicianUnix

Comment: but anyways, no one is compelling you to rely on this material, but although we're trying our level best to maintain academical accuracy to the best we can.