# What is authenticity of this forum?

Tags: discussion

I am an active member of stackoverflow and some other programmers related communities here. And they all are very good and working great. They are like must have for IT professionals.
But coming to religious matters, how is it good to let all kind of people answer the questions which must be answered by proper muftis, when we don't know the person answering is even a Muslim?? Or he is trying to inject some wrong beliefs in Islam? A person without any proper knowledge cannot give fatawa. So, how is this forum authentic and how is it not going to be disastrous as some people like me might give wrong opinions(which they thing are true) as they are not muftis and they are not supposed to give such statements and tell what Islam says about something when they don't have knowledge of it? And as lack of muftis here and no mechanism for answers to be checked by muftis, how can someone trust my answer?
A solution might be to have authenticated muftis on site, or a privilege like moderators a new privilege of MUFTI which will be awarded to only those who are actually mufti and they are able to prove it. They can mark any answer as approved by mufti, or their answers will be marked indicating they are mufti and their answers are more authentic.
Or anything like that to counter the fear i mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

We are not, nor have we ever been, a fatwa site.

If a question truly "must be answered by proper muftis" then it's [important](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) that it either be closed, downvoted into oblivion, or edited so that [it *can* work](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here. [We don't check credentials at the door](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/444/22), nor do we [filter scholarly answers from non-scholars](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1579/22); given how against the Stack Exchange philosophy it is, this is also unlikely to change any time soon.

The fact that so many questions here *aren't* curated thus just indicates that the community at large still feels that these *are* perfectly acceptable questions to ask random strangers on the Internet ([an opinion which I do not share](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1422/22)).

If you want to encourage users who actually know what they're talking about, it's important to [vote properly](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/); if you feel that an answer as-written is just not useful coming from a random stranger on the street, downvote it. If an answer as-written is well-written, well-referenced and informative, and which *would* be just as useful coming from Shaykh Muhammad Saalih al-Munajjid as it would from [Joe Six-Pack in Milwaukee](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/22), then vote it up.

But if people insist on voting for posts that do nothing more than copy the first link they pulled from Google and/or from their fatwa site of choice (something which literally *anybody* can do), then that's what you're going to get: A site full of non-experts [cribbing other people's work](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/22). The community reaps what it sows.

The voting mechanism is *foundational* to the Stack Exchange model; that's no different here than on any other Stack Exchange site. When applied properly, it does exactly what you're asking for here: It lets people *trust your answer*, because it was reviewed by and met the standards of the expert community. But if you build a site of non-experts, for non-experts, you're just going to end up with a bunch of answers that, as you fear, aren't (and probably *shouldn't* be) trusted by *anyone*.

Comment: Actually this forum CANNOT work like other stack exchange sites. Because like in stackoverflow i post a problem "Hay this is not working in my code where is the mistake." And someone points it out, you fix it, test if it works and thats all you care about.

Comment: But when it comes to islam you cannot test whether or not the answer IS what islam says about it. And about posting links to the Fatwa sites online, i think thats better than people like you and me giving their own fatwa's which they are not supposed to.

Comment: FATWA means nothing but someone's opinion.

Comment: Even on stackoverflow we get answers like "This will help:" and only stating some links to other sites having good explanation of the problems and there's no issue there in that. Infact if it solves the problem, those answers get high upvotes and acceptance in that community. But here(as of my experience) if someone try not to give his own opinion rather find and link to some proper fatwa, than that answer is either downvoted or is deleted. That's really the problem here.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal If you'd bothered to read through meta (including but hardly limited to the links I just posted), you'd see that almost all those exact same arguments have already been made. The whole point of this site is to gather an expert community who are willing and able to figure out *how* to make Stack Exchange work for Islam (Christianity and Judaism have figured it out), but pretty much all anybody does is complain that it *doesn't* work rather than put any effort to *making* it work.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal If you think a question needs to be answered by a mufti, and you answer the question even though you are *not* a mufti (rather than leaving it to be answered by someone who is actually *qualified* to answer it), then why *shouldn't* you be downvoted? That sounds like working-as-intended to me.

Comment: The whole point is that there is no way to get to know who is mufti and who is not, and which point of view is correct and which is not. That's exactly why we rely on mufti's. And if i link to a proper fatwa somewhere, why do i still get down vote? Aren't we supposed to take fatwa's from muftis? And if i have given a ref to a fatwa addressing that answer why i am getting down vote?

Comment: And i WANT this forum to work, this is not that i am only playing blame game here just because i got some down votes. This can be a great forum for whole world to know about islam. But for that to work we cannot rely on same rules as of programming or some other communities like that.