# Can anybody please edit my posts?

Tags: discussion, support

Can anyone edit my posts in such that the ban message will be lifted? Because I do not like to have this ban message and because I have trouble in grammar and in punctuations, I try my best but I don’t know. So, can you please edit my posts and delete permanently these posts: “Can I ask Allah To reverse time” and “How can I explain to someone that, no one know me what is Allah’s decision”? Because I myself don’t have enough reputations for this nor to delete any post permanently. And next time, I will try even better than now. Can you edit my posts in such that it will no longer appears to me this messages put as: on hold, unclear etc... or closed or locked? Only one time to edit my posts. And can you edit them in such that I can have answers? Only one time to make? Because I want to get rid of this ban message in very short period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble with grammar and punctuation is the minor issue with your posts.

Most of your questions and answer are of a kind that need a 50-100% re-edition as your questions are any thing but well-thought-out.
Your answers are hasty answers as if you are in a competition and just answer with the first thing that comes to your mind (or your first google finding) instead of doing some prior research, by reading the question and understanding what is asked and thinking of what is required to answer it before shooting out an answer (that tangents the topic of the question).
So we can't edit your posts as we would write new answers/questions instead and that's no more your "handiwork".

So you should do your homework first and check what you want to ask and what you want to answer before coming out with rather useless answers and too broad/unclear or off-topic questions.

My advice for you is never answer a question on a topic you have no idea about, if you have an idea check whether it is correct before answering or posting it.
Never ask a question unless you are sure it is clear and answerable you can check your questions here [Draft question review [trial run]](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/draft-question-review-trial-run) before posting it on the main site.

Many people think that the fact that they speak Arabic and can read it permit them to interpret the quran and hadith this is wrong! As else why do we have scholars who spent years of studying the texts before even answering a simple question?

Here an advice from Mark Twain:

> Mark Twain:
>   “It is better to keep your mouth shut and appear stupid than to open it and remove all doubt.”

See also: [What is the purpose of Islam SE and it's authenticity to answering questions about Islam?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/what-is-the-purpose-of-islam-se-and-its-authenticity-to-answering-questions-abo)

Comment: Fine, then I’ll try my best to correct them.

Comment: Then what I do with questions that are closed as duplicate?

Comment: Leave them if you agree or point at why you disagree!

Comment: Can you open “Is that true that studying in school is one of Allah’s commands”? Because I have made this time clear.

Comment: Yes! Finally, I have improved, you were right about it. But, what should I do if I have deleted my post and now is impossible to undelete? “Because”, there are also mistakes there. So, what should I do? “Because”, I suppose that I have finally edited the last post that needed to be improved.